# VSTS Load test results reporting not showing any data and graph when using Jmeter

Tags: graph, load-testing

[VSTS load test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pplMW.png) are not showing when I am running the jmeter script from VSTS. The response time etc graphs also doesn't show any data. I have followed below thread

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/78931/load-test-jmeter-not-displaying-results.html

I made changes in the script for load test duration etc, but still nothing is shown in the graph. The results are shown correctly in the report. I am using Jmeter 3.2.

There are no parameterization using csv etc. I only have one request to the api. Also the Jmeter assertion works fine on my local machine, but I don't see this in the VSTS report.

---

The VSTS log is displaying following

```
2018-06-20 03:13:51,827 WARN o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Error encountered during shutdown of jmeterplugin.CLTListenerPlugin@79207381 java.util.NoSuchElementException: null at java.util.Collections$EmptyIterator.next(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_172] at java.util.Collections.max(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_172] at rawsamplemanager.components.RawSamplesCache.getLastInterval(RawSamplesCache.java:116) ~[vso-clt-1.0.jar:?] at rawsamplemanager.HttpRawSamplesCollector.getLastIntervalId(HttpRawSamplesCollector.java:69) ~[vso-clt-1.0.jar:?] at jmeterplugin.CLTListenerPlugin.testEnded(CLTListenerPlugin.java:99) ~[vso-clt-1.0.jar:?] at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfEnd(StandardJMeterEngine.java:230) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748] at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:498) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748] at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_172] 
2018-06-20 03:13:51,827 INFO o.a.j.r.Summariser: summary = 0 in 00:00:00 = **/s Avg: 0 Min: 9223372036854775807 Max: -9223372036854775808 Err: 0 (0.00%)
```